# integral closure of $k[[t]]$ in algebraic closure of $k((t))$ is not Noether

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, valuation-theory

Let $k$ be a field.
I want to prove that the integral closure of $k[[t]]$ in algebraic closure of $k((t))$ (we call it $A$) is not a Noetherian ring.

Thank you for your help. Reference (a webpage, pdf, etc.) is also appreciated.

P.S

From the theory of extension of valuation, we can say $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is Noetherian as topological space.
Thus we can construct an example of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ which is not noetherian as a scheme but Noetherian as a topological space.

Comment: You need not reach for something so exotic to find a non-noetherian ring with noetherian spectrum. Consider $k[x_1,x_2,\cdots]/(x_1,x_2,\cdots)^2$, for instance.

Comment: Thank you, but I already knew the example you suggested.But, this（the title of the problem, with extension of valuation） is one of the most important example in which non-noether scheme SpecR is  noether as top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k$ has characteristic $0$ [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) $$A=\bigcup_{n\ge 1} \overline{k}[[t^{1/n!}]], \qquad \overline{k((t))} = A[t^{-1}]$$
and
$(t^{1/n!})$ is a strictly increasing sequence of ideals.

$Spec(A) = \{0\} \cup (\bigcup_{n\ge 1}(t^{1/n!}))$ is a 'Noetherian topological space'.

When $char(k)=p$ then $t^{1/(n+1)!-1/n!}$ is not integral over $k[[t]]$ thus $$(t^{1/n!})\subsetneq (t^{1/(n+1)!})\subsetneq A$$